# What is the best way to print a list on one line with separators?

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I am attempting to iterate over a list of strings and print them in one line, using "," as separators. However, contrary to the documentation, the print() function seems to ignore the separator and print the items as if the sep was not included. The code, along with the results, if below:

```
brothers = ['Larry', 'Harry', 'David']

for brother in brothers: 
    print(brother, sep=', ', end='\n')

Larry
Harry
David
```

Expected Result:
Larry, Harry, David

Comment: `end=', '` would do it

Comment: Thanks! So, if end=', ', would it make the sep=', ' superfluous?

Comment: it just depends - the answer you marked as solution needs `sep=","` and the deconstruction of `*brothers`  - what you started already decomposes the elements usiing your for-loop , you just need to hinder `print` to add the default `'\n'` when its done printing one element. the `sep` only comes into play if `print` has more then one value:  `print('A','B','b',sep='++++++')`

Comment: Readup: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print  and play around with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
>>> print(*brothers, sep=', ', end='\n')
Larry, Harry, David
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide all the values in the same call. This will work:

```
brothers = ['Larry', 'Harry', 'David']
print(*brothers, sep=', ', end='\n')
```

Quoting from https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print "Print **objects** to the text stream file"

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for *join*:

```
print ", ".join(brothers)
```